# How to list all the files in a folder that have a certain string in their file name on Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, command-line

For example, I have a folder `new_folder` and I have a lot of folders and files in this folder. I want to list all the files that have `math` in their file names. So files like `maths.txt`, `text.mathabc` would satisfy the requirement, and these files may be in some sub-folders of the `new_folder`. Is there a command that I can use to perform this action under `new_folder` as the current directory?

Answer (score 4):

`find` might be your friend here.

```
find . -iname "*math*" -type f -ls
```

This should search the current folder (".") and all sub-folders for files ("-type f") that have the string "math" in the name in a case insensitive way. It will finally print out an `ls -l` style list of the files found.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you're actually in the new directory or not (e.g. if you moved there with `cd`), and whether you want to just list them, or do something with them. If you're in the directory and just want to list them, use:

```
ls *math*
```

If you're not in the directory, you need to specify the path from where you are to the new folder, something like:

```
ls new_folder/*math*
```

Note that this will list the entire path for each file, not just the filenames.

If you want to do something with them, do *not* use `ls`. If the command can operate directly on a bunch of files, use the pattern directly with it, like this:

```
dosomethingwith *math*    # If you're in the directory
dosomethingwith new_folder/*math*    # If not
```

If you need to do something that needs files one-at-a-time, make a loop:

```
for file in *math*; do    # Or new_folder/*math* if not in the directory
    dosomethingwith "$file"
done
```

Comment: `ls` only searches the current directory. The files I am looking for may exist many levels down the current one, e.g. `new_folder/folder1/folder2/abc.math`

Comment: If you need to search subfolders, `find` is generally the way to go. See @7Reeds' answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use grep

```
ls -1 | grep "math"
```

Or you can use *find*